# Using the Google Maps API in a 3D Java scenario

Tags: java, google-maps

I am writing my dissertation this year in software engineering. I have a cool project in mind but wanted to ask if this was even possible first before I mention it to my tutor. If it is possible then it would be good if someone could point me in the right direction in achieving my goals.

My ideas is this. I want to make a Zombie survival game, generic and boring I know, but I want players to be able to run around in their own hometowns as if a zombie outbreak actually happened, the easiest way to do this would be to use the Google Maps API (I think) so maps are automatically created depending on a users home location.

And added feature would be to implement transport systems using local train stations so users can actually move to their friends areas in realtime on a multi-player platform.

So from what information I know already I would need these tutorials/resources.

- The ability to import real time google maps into a Java environment
- The ability to see where roads occur and where areas that can be walked on occur, maybe using the colour green as a basis for fields etc.. This is to ensure users can only walk within defined areas
- The ability to generate surroundings (such as houses and fences) next to roads and walkable areas rather than have the user running around on a flat 3D environment

I already have some knowledge on creating 3D environments as it is using the JWJGL library. Each of the points stated above are dependent on the previous bulleted point. Any feedback or constructive criticism is greatly appreciated. Even just a "What the hell are you even talking about" would be helpful also.

Glad to see your replies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using the Google Earth API: https://developers.google.com/earth/
You would have to get a web view of some kind, basically integrating a JavaScript application into your Java application. I would be cognizant of the terms of service though.